# Add 'referral cookie' to passport to be used in account creation

Tags: javascript, mean-stack

I'm building a partner program for my MEAN app.

**Here's the process on my site:**

1. A user visits my site through a referral link. Ex: http://example.com/ref/refname
2. A cookie with the key:value of ('ref':'refname') is created
3. The user is redirected to the /signup page (where I'm using passport with twitch oauth)
4. I would like to pull the cookie and add it to the user object in passport.js before the account is created.

How can I accomplish this? I'm using angular-fullstack and the npm module 'cookies', which can be seen here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies

> /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/cookies/lib/cookies.js:44   header
>   = this.request.headers["cookie"]
>                          ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

**Here's what I have in my modified passport.js...**

> var Cookies = require('cookies');
>
> var cookies = new Cookies();
>
> var referral = Cookies.get('ref');

I'm using ngCookies to set the cookie in angular, which is set fine, I'm just having a hard time getting it so I can add it to my User object in passport before creating the account.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just set this up for [Complice](https://complice.co/) last week. I just use the sessions system, rather than handling cookies directly. Here's some boilerplate code:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

// [other express/passport set-up stuff goes here]

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_STORE_SECRET,
  store: mongoStore,
  maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/ref/:refname', function (req, res) {
  req.session.ref = req.params.refname;
  res.redirect('/signup');
})

app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
  res.locals.ref = req.session.ref // if you want to use it in the page or whatever
  // ... other stuff here
});

app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
  var user = new User({
    // ...
    ref: req.session.ref
  })
  user.save(/* etc */)
});
```

Comment: You are amazing, thank you! I will accept the answer in 3 minutes (have to wait for some reason)

Comment: Haha yeah I don't answer new questions very often (usually I just answer questions that are problems I'm trying to solve myself and none of the existing solutions work) but I happened to be looking at the homepage and was like "hey I know this exactly :)"

Comment: Well I appreciate it very much. Have a great day :)